# is it required to pass timestamp value in entitymodel to insert a data into sql table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, timestamp

I am working on ado.net entity model and I want  to insert data into sql table. 
SQL table structure is shown below.

```
ID int,
Name varchar(20),
EventTime Timestamp
```

I am trying to insert data into SQL Table using entitymodel but data are not inserted in the table.

My passing arguments are `(1,"Test")` it's not working.

I figured out that when I pass `(1, "test", new Datetime())` then it works.

Can anyone let me know reason for that?

I understand that Timestamps value are automatically inserted by SQL server.

Comment: Not working 0 how exactly? What error do you get? From EF or from database?

Comment: Timestamps cannot be set/updated. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289114/how-to-add-timestamp-value-in-sql-server-2005-by-using-linq/11289199#11289199

Answer (score 1):

The "timestamp" data type gives you a binary value that automatically gets updated every time your field changes, but it won't give you a nice date/time value.

**Update:**
 as per **MSDN**: timestamp Is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary numbers within a database. timestamp is generally used as a mechanism for version-stamping table rows. The storage size is 8 bytes. The timestamp data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time.

**To record a datetime when the record has been inserted, use a datetime data type. You might add a column of type datetime to your table and set getDAte() to generate the datetime.**

Comment: My question is not about difference of Timestamp and DateTime field value in SQL.

Comment: I know what is Timestamp and DateTime so my question is totally different then what you answer.

Comment: I want to use TimeStamp only Not DateTime?

Comment: Reason behind using TimeStamp is specifically used with optimistic concurrency, where you don't lock a row when you read or write to it. This means that while you're updating a row client-side, another user might have updated the row, and if you write your changes to the row to the database, the other user's changes are overwritten. Using a timestamp column is one way to ensure this doesn't happen, by comparing the value of the timestamp originally retrieved with the current value in the database.

Comment: @Hari - I think the question is about TiimeStamp and he is having problem with time stamp and entity model. He is not going to use date time.